# Keras CNN Classifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, theano

I do have a question regarding the CNN in Keras if you would like to help me I would really appreciate this.

Disclaimer: I'm a noob in CNN and Keras, I'm just learning them right now.

---

**My Data:**

2 Classes (dogs and cats)

Traing: 30 pics each category

Test: 14 pics each category

Valid: 30 pics each category

---

**My code:**

```
data_path = Path("../data")

train_path = data_path / "train"
test_path = data_path / "test"
valid_path = data_path / "valid"

train_batch = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(directory=train_path,
                                                       target_size=(200, 200),
                                                       classes=animals,
                                                       batch_size=10)

valid_batch = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(directory=valid_path,
                                                       target_size=(200, 200),
                                                       classes=animals,
                                                       batch_size=10)

test_path = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(directory=test_path,
                                                     target_size=(200, 200),
                                                     classes=animals,
                                                     batch_size=4)

imgs, labels = next(train_batch)

model = Sequential(
    [Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(200, 200, 3)), Flatten(),
     Dense(len(animals), activation='softmax')])

model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_path, steps_per_epoch=4, validation_data=valid_batch, validation_steps=3, epochs=5, verbose=2)
```

---

**Here it's my error message:**

I've replaced the paths with ""

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 191, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(train_path, steps_per_epoch=4, validation_data=valid_batch, validation_steps=3, epochs=5, verbose=2)
  File "y", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "", line 1732, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "", line 185, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)
  File "", line 742, in get
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "", line 711, in get
    inputs = future.get(timeout=30)
  File "", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "", line 650, in next_sample
    return six.next(_SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid])
TypeError: 'PosixPath' object is not an iterator
```

---

Could anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong please? Also if this is an off-topic question just let me know where I can ask it.

Comment: You should pass the train_batch instead of train_path I believe. Try with this:
`model.fit_generator(train_batch, steps_per_epoch=4, validation_data=valid_batch, validation_steps=3, epochs=5, verbose=2)`

Comment: oh perfect, you were right, that was the mistake. Thanks you very much :D

Comment: I just turned my comment into an answer, since you told me it helped you solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are NOT passing the generator for the training, but the path for the files (you are using **`train_path`** instead of **`train_batch`**.

Whereas you need to pass a generator for object when using `.fit_generator()`:

```
model.fit_generator(train_batch, steps_per_epoch=4, validation_data=valid_batch, validation_steps=3, epochs=5, verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line isn't necessary

`imgs, labels = next(train_batch)`

from the [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)  fit_generator first argument is a generator object no a string as you have supplied. Like this

`model.fit_generator(train_path, steps_per_epoch=4, validation_data=valid_batch, validation_steps=3, epochs=5, verbose=2)`

Comment: I did comment that link but nothing change, everything it's exactly the same

Comment: did you also updated your `model.fit_generator` function as I stated above?